# Showing context menu for kendo UI treewiew by condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have a kendo UI treewiew, which represents some directory structure and context menu:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ContextMenu()
    .Name("menu")
    .Target("#treeview")
    .Orientation(ContextMenuOrientation.Horizontal)
    .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open =>
    {
        open.Fade(FadeDirection.In);
        open.Duration(500);
    }))
    .Items(items =>
    {
        items.Add()
            .Text("Test");

    })
    //.Events(e=>e.Open("contextOpen"))
)


<div class="treeview-back">
    @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("treeview")
        .TemplateId("treeview-template")
        .Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes
            .Name("checkedFiles")
            .CheckChildren(true)
        )
        .Events(events => events
            .Check("onCheck")
        )
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Model(m => m.Id("Path").HasChildren("HasChildren"))
        .Read("ReadDirectory", "Download"))   
    )
```

I need to show context menu only for elements that represent folders. But I can't find the way to show kendo context menu by condition. I added right click capturing method, which looks like this:

```
$("#treeview").on('mousedown', '.k-item', function (event) {
            var treeView = $('#treeview').data('kendoTreeView');
            var dataSource = treeView.dataSource;
            var itemUId = $(this).attr("data-uid");
            var node = dataSource.getByUid(itemUId);
            if (event.which === 3 && node.hasChildren) {
                event.stopPropagation(); // to avoid propagation of this event to the root of the treeview
                $('#treeview').data('kendoTreeView').select(this);
                ...//here I should prevent context menu from showing somehow
            }
        });
```

but I can't find the way to cancel context menu showing. I also tried to add open event to context menu, but I can't get selected item there. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show menu due to the condition use filter property of ContextMenu object:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ContextMenu()
    .Name("menu")
    .Filter(".menu-on")
)
```

It only shows menu for items that has class `menu-on`.

Secondly you have to add this class to all your folders. You should find by javascript all `<span class="k-in">` elements in your tree and add `menu-on` class to all elements associated with folders.